# Issue with Distance calculation google API in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-api, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using default google API javascript to calculate the Distance between two Longitudes and Latitudes.
Here is HTML and Angular javascript code for the same.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> AngularJS Tabs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/Test/AngularJS/JS1.js"></script>
<script 
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div data-ng-repeat = "x in data1 | orderBy:'Distance'">
{{x.Distance}}Km
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular JS Code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl",function ($scope,$rootScope,$http)
    { 



        alert ("IN");
        $scope.longitude ="72.865";
        $scope.latitude ="19.2290";
$scope.data1 =     [{"Latitude":"19.2285287999999994","Longitude":"72.8651116999999999","OfficeID":"34_NO","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.1802370000000018","Longitude":"72.8554148999999995","OfficeID":"37_ML","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"18.9288717999999996","Longitude":"72.822098699999998","OfficeID":"51_AI","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.1286862000000006","Longitude":"72.8677942000000058","OfficeID":"41_PN","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.1286862000000006","Longitude":"72.8677942000000058","OfficeID":"28_GAP","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.1921800000000005","Longitude":"72.9484999999999957","OfficeID":"36_NE","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.216841800000001","Longitude":"72.9744756999999993","OfficeID":"35_YP","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.230592399999999","Longitude":"72.8663173000000057","OfficeID":"33_GE","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.1589519999999993","Longitude":"72.8537749999999988","OfficeID":"39_NK","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"18.9346618999999983","Longitude":"72.8367776000000049","OfficeID":"50_TH","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.1252999999999993","Longitude":"72.9077000000000055","OfficeID":"42_KA","Distance": null},
            {"Latitude":"19.1252999999999993","Longitude":"72.9077000000000055","OfficeID":"43_KB","Distance": null}
    ];



var c =0;  
   for(c=0; c<$scope.data1.length; c++)
    {

            gelDistance(parseFloat($scope.data1[c].Latitude).toFixed(3),parseFloat($scope.data1[c].Longitude).toFixed(3),c);

 }



 function gelDistance(Latitude,Longitude,c) {

  var location1 = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.latitude,$scope.longitude);

      var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude);

          directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
          directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
          {
          suppressMarkers: true,
          suppressInfoWindows: true
          });
          var request = {
          origin: location1, 
          destination:location2,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          };


          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
          {

         // alert ('function'+c);
         //     alert (request);
           if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
               $scope.$apply( function(){ 
            //  alert ('responce'+c);
              $scope.distance=parseFloat(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
              $scope.temp=$scope.Distance;
              $scope.data1[c].Distance=$scope.distance;

               });
            }

          }

          );                       

   } ;

    });
```

The result i am getting from this code is :

```
1Km
2.8Km
7.8Km
9.3Km
13.4Km
13.4Km
27.1Km
28Km
36.1Km
39.4Km
Km
Km
```

The Driving distance calculation is skipped for some of the values. May i know the reason for this and please telme how can i resolve this issue. I have just given 12 sample values, where i have more than 30 to 40 values for which distance to be calculated.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem but you haven't defined your `$rootScope` .

Comment: and you haven't used the standard dependency hierarchy. I'm inserting a snippet for your reference which is from the official Angular JS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

So basically this is how it should look like (if you go by the docs):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope' , '$rootScope' , function ($scope,$rootScope,$http)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the issue was not with my code. Freely available google API service can serve only 10 requests per second.

So, only first 10 requests are getting served with distance calculation.

The solution would be adding a timeout between each requests.